# Wildcard to include all subfolders when compiling using esbuild

Tags: typescript, fastify, esbuild

When I am using esbuild I find I have to list all of the sub folders in order to get them to compile.

For example:

```
esbuild server/*.ts server/**/*.ts server/**/**/*.ts --bundle --platform=node --outdir=dist
```

I am building a fastify app with the `@fastify/autoload` plugin so not all of my files are imported and hence, can not all be located via imports from the main entry point.

How can I tell esbuild to look in every subfolder in `server` and compile all of the `.ts` files it finds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not need esbuild to achieve this task. Esbuild is a bundler, all I was looking to do was compile my Typescript code into Javascript.

I was able to achieve this by using the `ts-node` package. I replaced my script with the below and it has resolved my issues.

```
ts-node ./server/server.ts
```

I have, however, noticed that `ts-node` is noticeably slower than `esbuild`. Hopefully it will become faster over time.

Answer (score -1):

`esbuild server/**/*.ts --bundle --platform=node --outdir=dist` should do it?

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.